# Understanding Null move pruning

Tags: engines, programming

I have trouble understanding null move pruning. I understand the concept of a free move for the side that just played a move, but what I don't understand is the code part:

```
int score = -negamax(-beta,-beta+1,depht-1-R)
```

Why do we pass in for the second parameter -beta + 1, why not -alpha?

Comment: This is simply using the concept of null windows, whose name is unrelated by the way. We replace the alpha since for null-move pruning, we don't need to know the exact value of the resulting search, just whether or not it failed high for us (-beta) or not (-beta+1). Replacing alpha restricts the bounds of the search and thus saves us time by pruning branches that are irrelevant to whether or not the search will fail high or low.